# Using aws_kms_key forces instance replacement

Tags: terraform

I have a strange problem, I created "aws_kms_keys" which is fine and working okay, then I assign that created keys to my ebs_block with the following code :

```
  #root disk
  root_block_device {
    volume_size = "120"
    volume_type = "gp2"
    encrypted   ="true"
    kms_key_id  = aws_kms_key.aws-wm-wmad-prod.key_id
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
```

however if I run terraform apply it will attempt to replace the entire instance after it's already created.   `~ kms_key_id            = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:1433:key/9c93acdd-etc" -> "9c93acdd-etc" # forces replacement`
i'm using TF version 0.14.7 with provider version 3.72.0 was curious what is the workaround for this or fix for this ? or should i upgrade to the latest TF which might fix this?

I FOUND a workaround this using the following:

```
 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [root_block_device[0].kms_key_id]
  }
```

however it's annoying lol, not sure why this is even required but wanted some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround nor fix for that. That's how it works. Changes to [KmsKeyId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-template.html#cfn-ec2-instance-ebs-kmskeyid) require **replacement** and you can't change this behavior.

So you have to backup your data from the given EBS volume, make the replacement, and copy the data back.

Comment: Interesting, so if your increasing the server size by 1 count then it will require all other instance to be rebuilt , that's why you have to pretty much code in the ability to copy the data over? 
however when i run lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [root_block_device[0].kms_key_id]
  }
the error seems to go away?

Comment: @BoBhayani If you ` ignore_changes`, then your volume will not be encrypted, as you are ignoring changes to encryption.

Comment: that is why I'm confused I just tested this and seems like even with the lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [root_block_device[0].kms_key_id] there all the EBS volumes are still encrypted and I am able to increase instance size by 1 without having to destroy the and reforce creation of the instance again :) Maybe i discovered something by accident haha
  }

Answer (score 0):

If you add:

```
  lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [
        root_block_device[0].kms_key_id,
        security_groups
      ]
  }
```

The original creation will happen, but updates do not force a Destroy/Create
This allows updates to instances, without forcing replacement. Ie: Tags, etc. Unfortunately, it prevents updates to SGs.

I have a script to deploy 50+ VMs; it does not always succeed on the first try all the way through. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple fix for your situation. Using the `aws_kms_key.aws-wm-wmad-prod.arn` instead of `aws_kms_key.aws-wm-wmad-prod.key_id`. That's it!